# netcat or nc sending null character to remote server

Tags: java, linux, unix, netcat

Hi I am trying to send some string to remote server using following command:

```
    ##1.2.3.4 is IP address of remote server
    echo "hey" | nc 1.2.3.4 7728
    >> hey
    >> null
```

It is not coming out of loop and in the remote server I am encountering null pointer exception. Can anyone please help me to get around this error ?

## NPE:

```
New connection with client# 2 at Socket[addr=/1.2.3.4,port=55757,localport=7728]
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.o7planning.tutorial.socketthread.ServerProgram$ServiceThread.run(ServerProgram.java:85)
```

Need to know :

1. How to come out of the command ?
2. What to do to avoid Null Pointer exception.

PS: Client is running on Linux. and server is Java based.

## Server-code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerProgram {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

       ServerSocket listener = null;

       System.out.println("Server is waiting to accept user...");
       int clientNumber = 0;

       // Try to open a server socket on port 7777
       // Note that we can't choose a port less than 1023 if we are not
       // privileged users (root)

       try {
           listener = new ServerSocket(7722);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e);
           System.exit(1);
       }

       try {
           while (true) {
               // Accept client connection request
               // Get new Socket at Server.

               Socket socketOfServer = listener.accept();
               new ServiceThread(socketOfServer, clientNumber++).start();
           }
       } finally {
           listener.close();
       }

   }

   private static void log(String message) {
       System.out.println(message);
   }

   private static class ServiceThread extends Thread {

       private int clientNumber;
       private Socket socketOfServer;

       public ServiceThread(Socket socketOfServer, int clientNumber) {
           this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
           this.socketOfServer = socketOfServer;

           // Log
           log("New connection with client# " + this.clientNumber + " at " + socketOfServer);
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {

           try {

               // Open input and output streams
               BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketOfServer.getInputStream()));
               BufferedWriter os = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketOfServer.getOutputStream()));

               while (true) {
                   // Read data to the server (sent from client).
                   String line = is.readLine();

                   // Write to socket of Server
                   // (Send to client)                    
                   os.write(">> " + line);
                   // End of line.
                   os.newLine();
                   // Flush data.
                   os.flush();


                   // If users send QUIT (To end conversation).
                   if (line.equals("QUIT")) {
                       os.write(">> OK");
                       os.newLine();
                       os.flush();
                       break;
                   }
               }

           } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e);
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: We need to see the relevant parts of the server source code.

Comment: I'd assume that `is.readLine()` returns `null`. This does not occur because of null character being send, but rather the end of stream having been reached.

Comment: server code added.

Comment: @Teemu , yes I agree ...We can observe that on linux command line as well.